# Ruby on rails: equivalent rails query to get this->

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can i get this result from ruby on rails query?

```
 select post_id, count(post_id)
 from comments
 group by post_id
 order by count(post_id) desc
 limit 5
```

Comment: I'd suggest you accepted some of the answers and then check out this guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: I want to get those posts with most comments limit 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Active Relation is amazing. It's just this :

```
Comment.select("post_id, COUNT(post_id)").group("post_id").order("COUNT(post_id) DESC").limit(5).all
```

You should look more into it, it really is great.

Comment: Thanks jesse, but i want to get those posts with this post_id i got from Comment.select("post_id, COUNT(post_id)").group("post_id").order("COUNT(post_id) DESC").limit(5).all , how can i do this in one query ?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.